# Filterable Jquery Portfolio not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Im using this [Filterable Jquery Portfolio](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-jquery/)

My codes are as follow

View

```
<div class="genre">
<ul id="filter">
    <li class="current"><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Show</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Movie</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="album-list">
    @foreach (var video in Model)
    {
        <li class="@video.VideoType">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = video.Id })">
                <img height="100px" width="100px" alt="@video.Title" src="@video.ImageURL" />
                <span>@video.Title</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul#filter a').click(function() {
    $(this).css('outline','none');
    $('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');

    var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

    if(filterVal == 'all') {
        $('ul#album-list li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {

        $('ul#album-list li').each(function () {
            if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
});
});
```

Extract of rendered html

```
<div class="genre">

<ul id="filter">
    <li class="current"><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Show</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Movie</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="album-list">

        <li class="Show">

            <a href="/Store/Details/4">

                <img height="100px" width="100px" alt="Age of Conan" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/vapour/images/zero.jpg" />

                <span>Age of Conan</span>

            </a>

        </li>
```

Somehow, when i select Movie or Show, the respective items dont appear. All works though. did i make a stupid mistake somewhere? Thanks

*Update, Ok. discovered that if the li classes are in small caps, the items can be displayed. How do i change the ws to be able to work even though the first char is a capitalized? thanks

```
<li class="show">
```

Comment: Ok Fixed. Added @video.VideoType.ToString().ToLower() in the list class. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Ok Fixed. Added @video.VideoType.ToString().ToLower() in the list class. Thanks all